Two ThreadPoolTaskScheduler beans defined but all scheduled tasks are working on one
I want to create two beans returning same obj type:
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Configuration
    @EnableScheduling
    public class SchedulingConfig {


    @Bean(name = "schedulerHikari")
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler schedulerHikari() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setPoolSize(1);
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("scheduler-hikari-hc-");
        return scheduler;
    }


    @Bean(name = "schedulerJVM")
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler schedulerJVM() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setPoolSize(1);
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("scheduler-jvm-hc-");
        return scheduler;
    }
}

to create healthCheck classes:
    @Component
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Slf4j
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public class HikariCPCheck implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>,         SchedulingConfigurer {

    private final HikariDataSource dataSource;
    @Qualifier("schedulerHikari")
    private final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler schedulerHikari;
    @Value("${healthcheck.datasource.hikari.max-awaiting}")
    private final int maxAwaitingConnections;
    @Value("${healthcheck.datasource.hikari.scheduler-hikari-delay}")
    private final int initialDelay;
    @Value("${healthcheck.datasource.hikari.scheduler-hikari-rate}")
    private final int fixedRate;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(@NonNull ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            log.info("Successfully obtained connection from HikariCP");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            if (e.getMessage().contains("Timeout")) {
                log.error("HikariCP pool initialization failed: Connection timeout", e);
            } else {
                log.error("Failed to obtain connection from HikariCP", e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(schedulerHikari);
        PeriodicTrigger trigger = new PeriodicTrigger(Duration.ofMinutes(fixedRate));
        trigger.setInitialDelay(Duration.ofMinutes(initialDelay));
        taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(
                this::logConnectionPoolStatus,
                trigger
        );
    }

    private void logConnectionPoolStatus() {
        HikariPoolMXBean hikariPoolMXBean = dataSource.getHikariPoolMXBean();
        HikariConfigMXBean hikariConfigMXBean = dataSource.getHikariConfigMXBean();

        log.info("HikariCP Pool Name: {}", dataSource.getPoolName());
        log.info("HikariCP Total Connections: {}", hikariPoolMXBean.getTotalConnections());
        if (hikariPoolMXBean.getActiveConnections() >= hikariConfigMXBean.getMaximumPoolSize()) {
            log.warn("HikariCP Active Connections reached max pool size {active connections: {}, max pool size: {}}.", hikariPoolMXBean.getActiveConnections(), hikariConfigMXBean.getMaximumPoolSize());
        } else {
            log.info("HikariCP Active Connections: {active connections: {}, max pool size: {}}.", hikariPoolMXBean.getActiveConnections(), hikariConfigMXBean.getMaximumPoolSize());
        }
        log.info("HikariCP Idle Connections: {}.", hikariPoolMXBean.getIdleConnections());
        if (hikariPoolMXBean.getThreadsAwaitingConnection() > maxAwaitingConnections) {
            log.error("HikariCP Threads Awaiting Connection greater then limit {awaiting threads: {}, max: {}}.", hikariPoolMXBean.getThreadsAwaitingConnection(), maxAwaitingConnections);
        } else {
            log.info("HikariCP Threads Awaiting Connection: {awaiting threads: {}, max: {}}.", hikariPoolMXBean.getThreadsAwaitingConnection(), maxAwaitingConnections);
        }
    }
}

second class:
    @Component
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Slf4j
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public class JVMHealthCheck implements SchedulingConfigurer{

    private final OperatingSystemMXBean osMXBean = (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
    private final MemoryMXBean memoryMXBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
    @Qualifier("schedulerJVM")
    private final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler schedulerJVM;
    @Value("${healthcheck.jvm.processor.threshold}")
    private final int processorThreshold;
    @Value("${healthcheck.jvm.heap-memory.threshold}")
    private final int heapMemoryThreshold;
    @Value("${healthcheck.jvm.non-heap-memory.threshold}")
    private final int nonHeapMemoryThreshold;
    @Value("${healthcheck.jvm.scheduler-jvm-delay}")
    private final int initialDelay;
    @Value("${healthcheck.jvm.scheduler-jvm-rate}")
    private final int fixedRate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void logConnectionConfigStatus() {
        MemoryUsage heapMemoryUsage = memoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage();
        log.info("JVM Available Processors: {}", osMXBean.getAvailableProcessors());
        log.info("JVM Init Heap Memory Usage: {}", memoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getInit() / (1024 * 1024));
        log.info("JVM Max Heap Memory Usage: {}", memoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getMax() / (1024 * 1024));
        log.info("JVM Init Non Heap Memory Usage: {}", memoryMXBean.getNonHeapMemoryUsage().getInit() / (1024 * 1024));
        log.info("JVM Committed Non Heap Memory Usage: {}", memoryMXBean.getNonHeapMemoryUsage().getCommitted() / (1024 * 1024));
    }


    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(schedulerJVM);
        PeriodicTrigger trigger = new PeriodicTrigger(Duration.ofMinutes(fixedRate));
        trigger.setInitialDelay(Duration.ofMinutes(initialDelay));
        taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(
                this::logJVMUsageStatus,
                trigger
        );
    }

    private void logJVMUsageStatus() {
        log.error("wtf");
        if (osMXBean.getProcessCpuLoad()*100 > processorThreshold) {
            log.warn("JVM Process CPU usage reached threshold {usage: {}, threshold: {}}.", osMXBean.getProcessCpuLoad()*100, processorThreshold);
        }
        if (osMXBean.getProcessCpuLoad()*100 >= 99) {
            log.error("JVM Process CPU usage reached max {usage: {}, max: 100}.", osMXBean.getProcessCpuLoad()*100);
        }

        MemoryUsage heapMemoryUsage = memoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage();
        double usedHeapMemory = (double) heapMemoryUsage.getUsed() / heapMemoryUsage.getMax();
        double roundedHeapMemoryPercentage = Math.round(usedHeapMemory * 100 * 100.0) / 100.0;

        if (roundedHeapMemoryPercentage > heapMemoryThreshold) {
            log.warn("JVM Heap Memory usage reached threshold {usage: {}, threshold: {}}.", memoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed() / memoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getMax(), heapMemoryThreshold);
        }
        if (roundedHeapMemoryPercentage >= 99) {
            log.warn("JVM Heap Memory usage reached max {usage: {}, max: {}}.", roundedHeapMemoryPercentage, heapMemoryUsage.getMax());
        }

        MemoryUsage nonHeapMemoryUsage = memoryMXBean.getNonHeapMemoryUsage();
        double usedNonHeapMemory = (double) nonHeapMemoryUsage.getUsed() / nonHeapMemoryUsage.getMax();
        double roundedNonHeapMemoryPercentage = Math.round(usedNonHeapMemory * 100 * 100.0) / 100.0;

        if (roundedNonHeapMemoryPercentage > nonHeapMemoryThreshold) {
            log.warn("JVM Non Heap Memory usage reached threshold {usage: {}, threshold: {}}.",  roundedNonHeapMemoryPercentage, nonHeapMemoryThreshold);
        }
        if (roundedNonHeapMemoryPercentage >= 99) {
            log.warn("JVM Non Heap Memory usage reached max {usage: {}, max: {}}.", roundedNonHeapMemoryPercentage, nonHeapMemoryUsage.getMax());
        }
    }

    }

lombok.config:
lombok.copyableAnnotations+=org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier

app properties:
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=false

but all tasks are running on one thread of one scheduler:
2024-10-17 20:43:28,682 INFO  [scheduler-jvm-hc-1] b.c.h.HikariCPCheck: HikariCP Pool Name: name
2024-10-17 20:43:28,682 INFO  [scheduler-jvm-hc-1] b.c.h.HikariCPCheck: HikariCP Total Connections: 10
2024-10-17 20:43:28,682 INFO  [scheduler-jvm-hc-1] b.c.h.HikariCPCheck: HikariCP Active Connections: {active connections: 1, max pool size: 10}.
2024-10-17 20:43:28,683 INFO  [scheduler-jvm-hc-1] b.c.h.HikariCPCheck: HikariCP Idle Connections: 9.
2024-10-17 20:43:28,683 INFO  [scheduler-jvm-hc-1] b.c.h.HikariCPCheck: HikariCP Threads Awaiting Connection: {awaiting threads: 0, max: 3}.
2024-10-17 20:43:28,684 ERROR [scheduler-jvm-hc-1] b.c.h.JVMHealthCheck: wtf

I was trying with separate component classes for both beans - doesn't work. I was trying with @Resource but doesn't work either. What is the reason and how to fix this?

The problem is that Spring only uses a single ScheduledTaskRegistrar and that ScheduledTaskRegistrar schedules all tasks at once after all properties have been set. And that means it registers them on whatever ThreadPoolTaskScheduler happens to have been set last through taskRegistrar.setScheduler(). But I do not understand why you need two ThreadPoolTaskScheduler in the first place. A ThreadPoolTaskScheduler easily handles more than one scheduled task.

Thank You for quick explanation, the reason was just to have nice logs using prefixes :)

By calling ScheduledTaskRegistrar.setScheduler() you set the default scheduler. Once you set the default scheduler to schedulerHikari, and the second time you change it to schedulerJVM. If you want to use different schedulers, it is easier to specify them in the @Scheduled annotation.

@Scheduled(scheduler = "schedulerJVM", fixedRateString = "${healthcheck.jvm.scheduler-jvm-rate}", initialDelayString = "${healthcheck.jvm.scheduler-jvm-delay}")
public void logJVMUsageStatus() {
...
}


@Scheduled(scheduler = "schedulerHikari", fixedRateString = "${healthcheck.datasource.hikari.scheduler-hikari-rate}", initialDelayString = "${healthcheck.datasource.hikari.scheduler-hikari-delay}")
public void logConnectionPoolStatus() {
...
}


